# Json Object Array Length

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I'm working with some Json that is similar to:

```
{ 
   "Apps" : [
   { 
     "Name" : "app1",
     "id" : "1",
     "groups" : [ 
       { "id" : "1", "name" : "test group 1", "desc" : "this is a test group" },
       { "id" : "2", "name" : "test group 2", "desc" : "this is another test group" } 
     ]
   }
   ]
}
```

If I parse it in jquery to return an object and I'm iterating through the apps like so:

```
$.each(myJsonObject.Apps, function() { ... };
```

How can I get the length of `this.groups`  ?

I've tried

- this.groups.length
- this.groups.length()
- $(this).groups.length()

and I cannot find any decent documentation on multiple tier json objects that have good information.

Any links or examples or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't that just a typo? `groups` in the JSON is all lowercase, but your code samples have `Groups`.

Comment: even in the correct case it does not work. ill update my example

Comment: Are you sure? It works fine when I just try it out in the console.

Comment: try $(var.Apps[0].groups).length

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try:

```
$.each(myJsonObject.Apps, function(i, obj) { ... });

obj.Groups.length;
```

Comment: odd it doesnt work when i reference this... but if I reference myJsonObject it works.  ill accept once the limit expires ><

Answer (score 4):

Javascript is case sensitive. Change `this.Groups.length` to `this.groups.length`.

This code should work:

```
$.each(myJsonObject.Apps, function() { 
   alert(this.groups.length);
});
```

I have a working example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9D5Eu/1/)

To avoid this sort of problem, you should use a consistent capitalization. In Javascript, it is conventional to use camelCase.

Answer (score 2):

this works well:

HTML:

```
<span id="result"></span>
```

JS:

```
var myJsonObject = 
{ 
   "Apps" : [
   { 
     "Name" : "app1",
     "id" : "1",
     "groups" : [ 
       { "id" : "1", "name" : "test group 1", "desc" : "this is a test group" },
       { "id" : "2", "name" : "test group 2", "desc" : "this is another test group" } 
     ]
   }
   ]
};

$.each(myJsonObject.Apps, function(i, el) { 
    $("#result").html(el.groups.length);
});
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/adescalzo/9wu4E/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just have a simple typo in your code. JavaScript is case-sensitive, so `groups` is **not** the same as `Groups`.

If your JSON object has `groups` in all lowercase, like your example, then you only need to use `this.groups.length` inside the iteration function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
    function objectCount(obj) {

```
objectcount = 0;
$.each(obj, function(index, item) {
    objectcount = objectcount + item.length;
});
return objectcount;
}
objectCount(obj);
```

where obj is a json object with json array as sub objects

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

JSONObject myJsonObject = new JSONObject(yourJson);
int length = myJsonObject.getJSONArray("groups").length();
```