# javascript calculate quantity of elements inside a json tag

Tags: javascript

Hello I have a json in javascript like this:

```
{"data":[{"stuff":[
    {"onetype1":[
        {"id":1,"name":"John Doe"},
        {"id":2,"name":"Don Joeh"}
    ]},
    {"othertype2":[
        {"id":2,"company":"ACME"}
    ]}]
},{"otherstuff3":[
    {"thing":
        [[1,42],[2,2]]
    }]
}]}
```

I want to know how to calculate in javascript how many 'onetype' tags there are. In php I can request it with count but in javascript I tried with data.lenght and it did not work. Any idea how to do it?

Thank you very much

Comment: If you can use `JQuery` have a look at answers to [Json Object Array Length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586793/json-object-array-length) post.

Comment: I think that designating this question as off-topic is an overly strict interpretation of the guidelines...as far as I can see, the only condition it fails to meet is that it's not the "shortest code necessary" to reproduce the problem. But it's not a lot of code, and we are often asking new users to post *more* code to provide context, so this seems like a strange question to pick on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for `Object.keys(data).length`. There's a shim for older browsers here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Polyfill.

BTW there's no such thing as a "json tag" - the word "tag" the way you're using it applies only to HTML/XML.

Answer (score 0):

This is your nested object

```
var data = [{"stuff":[
    {"onetype1":[
        {"id":1,"name":"John Doe"},
        {"id":2,"name":"Don Joeh"}
    ]},
    {"othertype2":[
        {"id":2,"company":"ACME"}
    ]}]
},{"otherstuff3":[
    {"thing":
        [[1,42],[2,2]]
    }]
}]
```

This is how you access lengths and elements

```
data.length                          // 2
data[0].stuff.length                 // 2
data[0].stuff[0].onetype1.length     // 2
data[0].stuff[0].onetype1[0]         // Object {id: 1, name: "John Doe"}
data[1].otherstuff3.length           // 1
data[1].otherstuff3[0].thing.length  // 2
data[1].otherstuff3[0].thing[0]      // [1, 42]
```